# I'm using an Edge browser and are having browser recognition problems

Tags: microsoft-edge

I added a meta tag to the web page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="UA, UA-Platform, UA-Arch, UA-Model, UA-Mobile, UA-Full-Version">
```

But the results are as follows:

```
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"
```

What's the reason why "Edge" is missing in the brand name?

Comment: Can't replicate on 99.0.1150.39, https://browserleaks.com/client-hints correctly get " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="99" check your extensions or update your question with your code

Comment: I checked and found that it was 99.0.1150.39, but it is normal in Windows 10, but it cannot be imported in Windows 11.

Comment: Not sure if edge-detection is the best tag for this

Comment: Do you open the page in Edge browser? I can't reproduce the issue. My code is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8D2n.png) and it returns `sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="99"` in Edge Version 99.0.1150.39 in Win11. What about running [this page](https://browserleaks.com/client-hints) in Edge in your computer? Can you get the right result?